# Rejected migrations page erroring out

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, 500-server-error, migration-rejection

I noticed the 10k [rejected migrations list](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/rejected) on the 10k tools (`tools > migrations > rejected`) is currently taking me to the default error page:

[image]

I thought I should post this to make sure the cat is aware, and really workin on ur problemz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've fixed "the glitch."

A post is in there that was rejected not once but **TWICE**, and well, you see, `.ToDictionary()` just didn't care for that very much.  The fix will go out with the next build today.

Comment: Sanity.. sanity.. sanity check! ;)